# How to temporally make bodies in box2d act like sensors (let another bodies go through them)

Tags: ios, box2d, box2d-iphone

I know I can make b2Body sensor by setting special flag in b2BodyDef. But what I need is to temporally turn body into sensor, and then turn it back to not-sensor again. So I need a switch that will let another bodies to go through this body.

Thank you!

Comment: if you want just to allow bodies pass - then change b2Filter iVar of b2Fixture. You can read more in the box2d manual

Comment: I agree with Andrew, I think the best way is to alter the filtering using maskBits, and category bits, or you can dynamically destroy the existing fixture and then create a temporary fixture that is set to be a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set its position to somewhere where is really far away from you and set it back later.